# Does anyone have a sample for drawing a subdivided icosahedron in javascript, that they would be able to share?

Tags: webgl

Does anyone have a sample for drawing a subdivided icosahedron in javascript, that they would be able to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find some code off of this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561093/how-to-generate-a-subdivided-icosahedron and do the conversion to JS yourself.